# /dev/shm上のファイルの存在確認

Tags: c

使用しているシステムは、tmpfsが/dev/shmにマウントされています。
tarファイルを/dev/shmにコピーし、展開しました。

```
root@xxx:~# ls -al /dev/shm/update
drwxrwxrwx    2 xuser    xuser          100 Oct 21 18:03 .
drwxrwxrwt    3 root     root           100 Oct 21 18:03 ..
-rwxr-xr-x    1 xuser    xuser         1717 May 13 02:35 bootmisc.sh
-rw-r--r--    1 xuser    xuser           89 Jul 23 06:14 mount.blacklist
```

の様にファイルが見えています。
C言語でソフトを開発しており、ファイルの存在チェックをstat()で行なっています。
USBメモリや/home/rootなどでは、正常に結果が返ります。

```
if (stat("/dev/shm/update/bootmisc.sh",&st) != 0){
   printf("file nothing\n");
}
```

とチェックすると、=0　が返りません。
tmpfs上のファイルをstat()ではチェック出来ないのでしょうか？
その場合、代替え手段は無いでしょうか？

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: `printf("file nothing\n");` の代わりに `perror("stat");` を追加するとエラーの原因が分かるかもしれません。

Comment: アドバイス、ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

自己解決出来ました。

if (stat(" /dev/shm/update/bootmisc.sh",&st) != 0){
   printf("file nothing\n");
}

ファイル名指定の”....”の先頭に空白があったのが原因でした。
空白があった場合、スキップしてくれると思い、なかなか原因にたどり着けませんでした。

お騒がせしました。